# What happens to "migrated" questions?

Tags: support, migration

Which of these happens to "migrated" questions?

1. The question is on both sites and synchronizes answers, comments and edits.
2. It's copied from one site to the other. Therefore, it doesn't synchronize between both sites.
3. It's removed from the first site.
4. Other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Choices 2 and 3 are both partially correct. Migrated questions are copied over and do not synchronize between sites; the original is automatically closed on the original site. After a while, it is deleted from the original site.

Example: [**this question on Programmers**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/221937/revisions) was migrated to [**this question on Code Review**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37806/can-this-code-that-calculates-kills-and-deaths-in-a-game-be-written-to-execute-f). The original post was simultaneously locked by Community (a "moderator" that is actually a bunch of automatic clean-up processes built into the software). Eventually, the original was automatically deleted by Community.

Comment: As a related follow-up, what happens with reputation gains? If I ask a question on Programmers and get one up vote, then it gets migrated to Code Review and I get three more, do I get the new rep on Code Review? What if I don't have an account there?

Comment: The system would automatically create a new account for you, and you would receive points on the new site for any existing votes.

Comment: Your answer seems like 3 not 2

Comment: It's really both. The migrated question lingers on the original site for a while, but it is closed and locked. It's not deleted until later (roughly a month, in my experience).